# Simple Service or library to tile GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, leaflet, tile-map-service

TL;DR: is there a Tile Map Service that can generate tiles on the fly given a GeoTIFF image as input. Alternatively, can `gdal2tiles.py` be used to generate only 1 tile instead of all tiles for a zoom level, or is there another CLI tool, nodejs oder Python library that can do that?

---

I'm currently developing an application which utilizes GeoJSON features and displays them in the browser with Leaflet. The conversion from GeoJSON to GeoTIFF raster images was fast and easy with `gdal_rasterize`, however the tiling with `gdal2tiles.py` takes a very long time to generate. Therefore I would like to generate the tiles on the fly only when they are requests from Leaflet and then cache them for future use (I don't care if it takes a few seconds to load, that's still better than waiting an hour to generate all tiles, at least as long as I'm developing).

At first I was naive and thought I can write my own Tile Map Service which checks if the tile exists and if not generates it with `gdal2tiles.py` however there are two problems

1. `gdal2tiles.py` generates all tiles for a specified zoom value
2. Suppose Leaflet request request the tiles 1,1 1,2 1,3 for zoom 5 and so on, each request would trigger `gdal2tiles.py` which generates every tile at zoom 5 which is redundant because it would generate the same tiles for each request

Therefore I would need some sort of render queue that only adds a render request for a given zoom level if it doesn't already exist in the queue.

At this point I thought there must be some already existing TMS that do exactly this: take many request for tiles in parallel and return them on the fly in a performant way.

But the only TMS I could find were things like mapnik that can generate tiles from OSM data or TileCache that can cache requests from an existing TMS.

Comment: Maybe mapnik in combination with Mapproxy - https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/sources.html#mapnik - will give you also the possibility to configure a cache in mapproxy. But why not import Geojson into Postgres and host it using Geoserver?

Comment: If you have access to an internet-accessible server, then using Geoserver with it's built in GeoWebCache is a good solution for this sort of thing.  You can install it on you local computer, but that may not be accessible from the internet, so you would likely want to install it on an internet-accessible server.